# left and right images, responsive to page size and centered

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit out of practice and frustrated because I've done this 100 times in the past but now I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I want to get rid of the gap between the image and the text, I also want it to be centered (image to the far side of the container with the text showing up next to it and taking up whatever remaining space is left in the container).

Edit: Basically I want it to look like this and work with any page size:
https://imgur.com/SHHI61o
On mobile it would look something like this:
https://imgur.com/H1wXeIK

I am trying to align the images to the sides, and text next to the image.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and would greatly appreciate some help.

Here's my code so far:

https://codepen.io/Squeezitgirdle/pen/OJwLxwN

```css
.conversation {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}
.right-msg 
{
position: relative;
max-width:50%;
min-height: 30px;
color:#ffffff;
padding:9px 9px 9px 15px;
margin-bottom:20px;
background: black;
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

.right-msg:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 6px 0 6px 12px;
border-color: transparent rgba(0,0,0,1);
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
right: -8px;
top: 6px;
}
.left-msg 
{
position: relative;
max-width:50%;
min-height: 30px;
color:#ffffff;
padding:9px 9px 9px 15px;
margin-bottom:20px;
background: rgba(66,66,66,1);
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

.left-msg:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 6px 12px 6px 0;
border-color: transparent rgba(66,66,66,1);
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
left: -8px;
top: 6px;
}

.right-msg {
float:left;
text-align: right;
}

.left-msg {
float:right;
}
.left-img {
margin-right:  auto;
margin-bottom:10px;  
  max-width:20%;
}
.right-img {
  margin-left: auto;
    padding-bottom:-10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
  max-width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="conversation">
<div class='row'>
                <div class='right-msg'>Msg words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words</div>
                <div><img class='right-img'  src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png"></div></div>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='left-msg'><span class='mirror'>hey words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words</span></div>
                <div ><img class='left-img' src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png"></div></div>
<div class='row'>
                <div class='right-msg'>Msg 3</div>
                <div><img class='right-img' src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png"></div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='left-msg'><span class='mirror'>Msg Close</span> </div>
                <div><img class='left-img' src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png"></div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
                <div class='right-msg'>Msg 4</div>
                <div><img class='right-img' src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a reference picture of what it should like?

Comment: Something like this: https://imgur.com/SHHI61o
It looks pretty good when I shrink the page, except for the two circled spots: https://imgur.com/KypF8LG one of the messages ends up hiding within another div container, and there's a massive gap between text.  Oh and the last image + text should be at the right side.

In short, images should be on the side of the screen with text taking up the remaining space of the container.

Comment: Hopefully this is more clear.
Basically I want the left image + speech bubble to be horizontal and aligned on the left side of the screen.

Right image + speech bubble aligned on the right side of the screen. With no gap between the speech bubble and image. 

 I'm using max-width: % to optimize it for any browser size which may be causing some of the issue.  That and my float properties are probably wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code

```css
.conversation {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}
.right-msg 
{
position: relative;
max-width:50%;
color:#ffffff;
padding:9px 9px 9px 15px;
margin-bottom:20px;
background: black;
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

.right-msg:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 6px 0 6px 12px;
border-color: transparent rgba(0,0,0,1);
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
right: -8px;
top: 6px;
}
.left-msg 
{
position: relative;
max-width:50%;
min-height: 30px;
color:#ffffff;
padding:9px 9px 9px 15px;
margin-bottom:20px;
background: rgba(66,66,66,1);
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

.left-msg:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 6px 12px 6px 0;
border-color: transparent rgba(66,66,66,1);
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
left: -8px;
top: 6px;
}


.row{
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  align-items: start;
}

.row.left{
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.row.right{
  justify-content: end;
    margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.row.left .right-msg::after{
  right: usnet;
  left: -7px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.row.right{
  text-align: right;
}
.row.left .right-msg {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.row img, .row img-box{
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="conversation">
    <div class='row right'>
                <div class='right-msg'>
          Msg words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words
      </div>
                <div class="img-box">
          <img class='right-img'  src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png">
                </div> 
            </div>
  
  <div class='row left'>
                <div class='right-msg'>
          Msg words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words
      </div>
                <div class="img-box">
          <img class='right-img'  src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png">
                </div> 
            </div>
  
  <div class='row left'>
                <div class='right-msg'>
          Msg words word
      </div>
                <div class="img-box">
          <img class='right-img'  src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png">
                </div> 
            </div>
  
  <div class='row right'>
                <div class='right-msg'>
          Msg words
      </div>
                <div>
          <img class='right-img'  src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png">
                </div> 
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! 
I had to fix some of the HTML (left-msg and left-img class), just in case anyone see's this in the future.
But this immediately resolved my issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I changed some pieces in your code:

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}



.conversation {
    max-width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.row-r {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: calc(12em + 8px + 4em);
}
.row-l {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding-right: calc(12em + 8px + 4em);
}
.row-l > div:last-of-type {
    order: -1;
}

.right-msg {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: fit-content;
    margin: 0 8px 20px 0;
    padding: 9px 9px 9px 12px;
    color:#fff;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.right-msg:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px 0 6px 12px;
    border-color: transparent rgba(0,0,0,1);
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    right: -8px;
    top: 6px;
}

.left-msg {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: fit-content;
    margin: 0 0 20px 8px;
    padding: 9px 9px 9px 12px;
    color:#fff;
    background: rgba(66,66,66,1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.left-msg:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px 12px 6px 0;
    border-color: transparent rgba(66,66,66,1);
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -8px;
    top: 6px;
}

img {
    width: 12em;
}
```

```html
<div class="conversation">

    <div class='row row-r'>
        <div class='right-msg'>Msg words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words</div>
        <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='row row-l'>
        <div class='left-msg'>
          hey words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words</div>
        <div ><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png"></div>
    </div>

    <div class='row row-r'>
        <div class='right-msg'>Msg 3</div>
        <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png"></div>
    </div>

    <div class='row row-l'>
        <div class='left-msg'>Msg Close</div>
        <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png"></div>
    </div>

    <div class='row row-r'>
        <div class='right-msg'>Msg 4</div>
        <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pXN7qwv.png"></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: This also worked, thank you! 
When I get back on a PC tomorrow I'm going to review yours and the other guys code so I can see where I went wrong. Thanks again!